# How to use Playa in Low Variables?

Tags: playa, low-variables

Given a Playa field in Low Variables called `widgets`, how would I output the title of each widget? Below is what I'd expect, but it outputs nothing.

```
      {exp:low_variables:parse var="widgets"}
        {title}
      {/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps add screenshots of the Widgets variable type settings, the variable in LV itself and any output from the Template Debugger that mentions the LV tags?

Comment: @Low, I'll email the screenshots and post a solution back here, if we/I find one.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue. It was/is a bug in Playa. Pixel and Tonic now knows about it and will include a fix in the next release. In the meantime, here is my solution:

Change Line 2484 of ft.playa.php to...

```
$data = array(
'parent_var_id' => $this->var_id,
'parent_is_draft' => 0
);
```

Basically added 'parent_is_draft' => 0

Answer (score 1):

I'm just confirming that this works in Playa 4.4.4 + Low Variables 2.3.5 with EE 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

Have you seen [Low's answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5302/563)?  His first example should work for you:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_settings_home_feature_items" limit="3"}
    ...more code here...
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

If it's not working, can you post your EE version, Playa version, and LV version?

Thanks!

-Lisa, P&T

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much exactly what I did, but no luck.

Comment: EE 2.5.3, LV 2.3.5, Playa 4.4.2

Comment: I can reproduce this and will ask one of my devs to have a look. Thank you Matt!

Comment: I'm seeing this also, using EE 2.6.1, LV 2.3.5, Playa 4.4.3.

Comment: I am running into this issue as well using EE 2.6.1, Playa 4.4.5, and LV 2.4.0. The single low variable is returns a proper array -- for example, {var_name} returns an array like "[10] [this-is-a-stand-in-title] This is a stand in title". However, wrapping in a tag pair is returning no results -- for example {exp:low_variables:pair var="var_name"}...code...{/exp:low_variables:pair}. Is this reproducible for anyone else with this setup (knowing that Playa 4.4.4 addressed this issue)?

Comment: @ShananGalligan I am having the exact issue you are on EE 2.7.1, Playa 4.4.5 and LV 2.4.0. Not only does the exp:low_variables:parse tag pair not return anything, but the entire page renders blank for me. But I also can’t seem to intercept any PHP errors.

Comment: @ShananGalligan I managed to get an error message out finally... see my post at https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_variables_playa_field_problem#reply_13087037 and let me know if you get the same thing?

Comment: @ShananGalligan Strange, I went to Addons->Fieldtypes->Playa, got a database error, then refreshed that page and it magically loaded, and now my error is gone on the front end as well.