# Playa not working with Low Variables

Tags: playa, low-variables

I have just updated to Playa 4.4.3. I read there was bug with Low Variables and Playa, and that it was supposed to be fixed on the new Playa release.

I can't get Playa to work at all.

I've tried many many things. This is my basic code:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_sidebar" multiple="yes"}
  {title}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, the `multiple="yes"` parameter will do nothing here, as the variable is a Playa variable type. The `multiple` param is only valid [for some of the native variable types](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/tags#parse-tag).

Answer (score 4):

There is a bit of a bug in Playa that impacts Low Variables:

exp_playa_relationships has parent_var_id field. It's supposed to be either 0 or 1. Low Variables sets it to NULL due to an oversight in our code. The solution  was to set the column to 0 for rows, that were not 1.

We'll have a fix for this included in Playa in the future, but for right now, modifying your database that way should fix this.  Alternatively, there is a [temporary hack](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/10476/563) you can utilize which doesn't require muddling in the database,  and will be overwritten in the fixed version of Playa.

Comment: I have tried the hack with no luck.  I also tried editing the DB

Comment: If you want to email support@pixelandtonic.com with some Super Admin and FTP access we should be able to help out on this.

Comment: I got it working.  I cleared all cache, restarted MAMP, restarted MY Machine, deleted the playa field and recreated one with a new name. Thank you

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Can you please be specific about what needs to be done to fix it? Looking at my existing data it looks like parent_var_id is an integer between 1 and 5. Should I change it so the default is 0, if not 1, and start over? I made the code fix you suggested but it did not do anything.